Sum of topological interior and topological interior of the sum
In Banach spaces, or on a generic TVS of infinite dimension, i think that doesn't exists any inclusion relation beetween the topological interior of the sum of two subset and the sum of the topological interior of them.
However i can't find some counterexamples. Someone can help me?

In a Banach space, or more generally a locally convex Hausdorff TVS, any proper linear subspace has empty topological interior, so the latter is basically trivially a subset of the former.

You are right. This Is a typo, i' m interested to subset case

The latter is, in fact, still a subset of the former, though this is less trivial. The observation here is that, if $B$ is a TVS, $U \subset B$ is open, and $V \subset B$ is an arbitrary subset, then $U + V$ is open. Indeed, addition by a fixed $v \in B$ is a homeomorphism of the space, so $U + v$ is open. Hence, $U + V = \cup_{v \in V} (U + v)$ is a union of open sets, whence open.
Now, applied to the current case, let $X, Y \subset B$ be two arbitrary subsets of a TVS $B$. Then $\text{int}(X) + \text{int}(Y)$ is open. It is also clearly a subset of $X + Y$, so by definition of interior, we see that $\text{int}(X) + \text{int}(Y) \subset \text{int}(X + Y)$. (In fact, this tells you even $(X + \text{int}(Y)) \cup (\text{int}(X) + Y) \subset \text{int}(X + Y)$.)
